# Conversion to base $9$

Tags: arithmetic

Where am I going wrong in converting $397$ into a number with base $9$?

$397$ with base $10$ $$= 3 \cdot 10^2 + 9 \cdot 10^1 + 7 \cdot 10^0$$  To convert it into a number with base $9$ 
$$3 \cdot 9^2 + 9 \cdot 9^1 + 7 \cdot 9^0 = 243 + 81 + 7  = 331$$
But answer is $481$?????

Comment: You started with a number in base $9$ and converted it to base $10$ rather than the reverse.

Comment: To convert to base $9$ from base $10$, you could find the highest power of $9$ (e.g. $9,81,729$ ...) that is less than your number, then the largest multiple of that power that is still less than your number will be your left-most digit. So, in the case of $397_{10}$, the largest power of $9$ that will fit is $81$ (since $729$ is too large), and you can fit four $81$s: $4 \cdot 81=324< 397$ (five is too many, since $5 \cdot 81 = 405 > 397$. This means that the leftmost digit must be $4$. We are left with $397 - 4 \cdot 81 =73$. Now, find the largest multiple of $9$ that's less than $73$, etc.

Comment: The operation you've done is convert $(397)_9$ to base $10$.

Comment: One obvious sanity check is that if converting from a bigger base to a smaller number you should get a larger answer and visa versa. You can easily check your answer by converting it back to decimal to see if you get what you started with.

Answer (score 7):

$481_{[9]} = 4\,\cdot\,81 +8\,\cdot9+1\,\cdot\,1 = 324 + 72 + 1 = 397_{[10]}$

The conversion you presented is incorrect, you converted $397_{[9]}$ into $331_{[10]}$, which is not what you want.

To convert it properly:

$397/9 = 44$ (remainder = $1$)

$44/9 = 4$ (remainder = $8$)

$4/9 = 0$ (remainder = $4$)

The remainders give the result: $\boxed{397_{[10]}=481_{[9]}}$

Answer (score 7):

You cannot simply keep the same coefficients but change the $10$'s to $9$'s. What you must do is something like the following:
$$\begin{align}397&=3\times \color{red}{10}^2+9\times\color{red} {10}^1+7\times \color{red}{10}^0\\&=3\times(9+1)^2+9\times(9+1)+7\times 1\\&=3\times\color{blue}9^2+(3\times18+3)+\color{blue}9^2+\color{blue}9^1+(7)\\&=4\times \color{blue}9^2+(6\times9)+(10)+\color{blue}9^1\\&=4\times \color{blue}9^2+8\times \color{blue}9^1+1\times \color{blue}9^0\end{align}$$

What you did was simply change the tens in red to nines without doing any intermediate steps.

Comment: I love that the three answers right now are all using different methods to convert bases :)

Comment: I had not seen this method before but it's a nice approach. I would have used repeated division and took the remainders as @DanielCunha did because that's the way I was taught to convert decimal to binary but it works with any base.

Comment: @WarrenHill I sometimes use this approach, especially when the bases are so close together (like $9$ and $10$ are only $1$ apart, so you only pick up small numbers with the bracket expansion).

Comment: @Warren We can do this much more efificiently if we exploit the recursive  *Horner* form of radix notation - see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that

$$ (397)_{10} = 3 \cdot 10^2 + 9 \cdot 10^1 + 7 \cdot 10^0 \ne 3 \cdot 9^2 + 9 \cdot 9^1 + 7 \cdot 9^0 = (397)_9. $$

What we are trying to do is solve

$$ (397)_{10} = 3 \cdot 10^2 + 9 \cdot 10^1 + 7 \cdot 10^0 = a \cdot 9^2 + b \cdot 9^1 + c \cdot 9^0 = (abc)_9 $$

To find $a$ we take as many copies of $81$ from $397$ as we can:

$$ 397 - 4 \cdot 81 = 73. $$

Thus $a = 4$. Next, we take as many copies of $9$ from $73$ as we can:

$$ 73 - 8 \cdot 9 = 1, $$

so $b = 1$. Lastly, we take as many copies of $1$ from $1$ as we can:

$$ 1 - 1 \cdot 1 = 0. $$

Hence $c = 1$. Therefore the answer is $$(397)_{10} = (481)_9.$$

Comment: Nice answer, +1! I think you should mention that $9^3 = 729>397$ is too large to be considered, which is why you are starting from $9^2 = 81$, instead of a higher power of $9$. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

As I [explained in 2011,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50122/242) one *easy* way is to write the number in Horner form in the original base, then do the base conversion from the inside-out, e.g. below where $\rm\color{#c00}{red}$ means radix $9$ notation

$$\begin{align} 397 
\,&=\, (3\cdot 10\, +\, 9)\,10 +7\\
&=\, (\color{#c00}{3\cdot 11+10})10+7\\
&=\qquad\quad\ \  \color{#c00}{43\cdot 11}+7\\
&=\qquad\qquad\ \ \ \color{#c00}{473}+7\\
&=\qquad\qquad\ \ \ \color{#c00}{481}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a layout of the conversion algorithm (successive Euclidean divisions)
$$\begin{array}{ccrcrc*{10}{c}}
&&44&&4 \\
9&\Bigl)&397&\Bigl)&44&\Bigl)& \color{red}{\mathbf 4}\\
&&\underline{36}\phantom{7}&&\underline{36}\\
&&37&&\color{red}{\mathbf 8} \\
&&\underline{36} \\
&&\color{red}{\mathbf 1}
\end{array}$$
This is based on *Horner's scheme*:
\begin{align}
[397]_{10}&=9\cdot 44+ \color{red}1=9(9\cdot 4+\color{red}8)+\color{red}1=9^2\cdot\color{red}4+9\cdot\color{red}8+1\cdot \color{red}1.
\end{align}

Comment: But no division is needed if we use Horner optimally - see my answer.

Comment: That''s fine but it's no so easy *in practice* to do operations in another base, especially if you have to carry digits.